# Can someone explain this recursive for me?

Tags: python, recursion, python-2.x

I get this code from leetcode.

```
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
         if n == 0: 
             return 1
         if n == -1: 
             return 1 / x
         return self.myPow(x * x, n / 2) * ([1, x][n % 2])
```

This code is used to implement `poe(x, n)`, which means `x**n` in Python.

I want to know why it can implement `pow(x, n)`.

It looks doesn't make sense...

I understand

```
if n == 0: 
and
if n == -1:
```

But the core code:

```
self.myPow(x * x, n / 2) * ([1, x][n % 2])
```

is really hard to understand.

BTW, this code only works on Python 2.7. If you want to test on Python 3, you should change

```
myPow(x*x, n / 2) * ([1, x][n % 2])
```

to

```
myPow(x*x, n // 2) * ([1, x][n % 2])
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's tagged as `python-2.x` though. But yeah good to mention.

Comment: *Though this is tagged Python 2, since it assumes `/` is flooring division; replace `/` with `//` and it works everywhere.

Comment: Why do you need a class? Why not just `def myPow(x, n)`?

Comment: `[1, x][n % 2]` can be expressed much clearer as `x if n % 2 else 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive function is to compute power (most probably *integer*, non negative or `-1`, power) of a number, as you might have expected (something like `x = 2.2` and `n = 9`).

*(And this seems to be written for `Python 2.x` (due to the `n/2` having expected result of `integer` instead of `n//2`))*

The initial `returns` are very straight-forward math.

```
 if n == 0: 
     return 1
 if n == -1: 
     return 1 / x
```

When the power is `0`, then you return `1` and then the power is `-1`, you return `1/x`.

Now the next line consists of two elements:

```
self.myPow(x * x, n/2)
and
[1, x][n%2]
```

The first one `self.myPow(x * x, n/2)` simply means you want to make higher power (not `0` or `-1`) into half of it by squaring the powered number `x`

*(most probably to speed up the calculation by reducing the number of multiplication needed - imagine if you have case to compute `2^58`. By multiplication, you have to multiply the number `58` times. But if you divide it into two every time and solve it recursively, you end up will smaller number of operations).*

Example:

```
x^8 = (x^2)^4 = y^4 #thus you reduce the number of operation you need to perform
```

Here, you pass `x^2` as your next argument in the recursive (that is `y`) and do it recursively till the power is `0` or `-1`.

And the next one is you get the modulo of two of the divided power. This is to make up the case for **odd** case (that is, when the power `n` is odd).

```
[1,x][n%2] #is 1 when n is even, is x when n is odd
```

If `n` is `odd`, then by doing `n/2`, you lose one `x` in the process. Thus you have to make up by multiplying the `self.myPow(x * x, n / 2)` with that `x`. But if your `n` is not odd (even), you do not lose one `x`, thus you do not need to multiply the result by `x` but by `1`.

Illustratively:

```
x^9 = (x^2)^4 * x #take a look the x here
```

but

```
x^8 = (x^2)^4 * 1 #take a look the 1 here
```

Thus, this:

```
[1, x][n % 2]
```

is to multiply the previous recursion by either `1` (for even `n` case) or `x` (for odd `n` case) and is equivalent to ternary expression:

```
1 if n % 2 == 0 else x
```

Comment: Thank you for your explain! It is spectacularly clear! But why does this code want to use (x^2)^4 rather than x^8? x^8 seems more clear!

Comment: @MarsLee I guess, it is likely to speed up the computation process by having less `*` let say for very large `n` (imagine `2^50` case)

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question. So if n is negative, what will happen?

Comment: Will it work like this?             x^-9 = (x^2)^-5 * x

Comment: I have tried it in python 3.5.1: -9/2 == -4.5 So this might only work in python 2.7

Comment: @MarsLee you are right... it is likely for -1 to positive number, because if n is negative, then the n % 2 will only return 0 or 1

Comment: Besides, since this code is accepted in Leetcode. So this code might be correct. And according to the logic, -9/2 == -5 in this code, or the result will be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105533/discussion-between-mars-lee-and-ian).

Comment: @MarsLee best to check the result, if you have a testing facility nearby I mean..

Answer (score 0):

This is divide and conquer technique. The implementation above is a fast way of computing exponentiation. At each call, half of the multiplications are eliminated.

Assuming that n is even, x^n can be written as below (If n is odd, it requires one extra multiplication)

```
x^n = (x^2)^(n/2)
or
x^n = (x^n/2)^2
```

The function shown above implements the 1st version. It's easy to implement the 2nd one also (I removed recursion base cases below)

```
r = self.myPow(x,n/2)
return r * r * ([1, x][n % 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer might be below

```
class Solution:
    def myPow(self, x: float, n: int) -> float:

        if n == 0: 
            return 1
        if n > 0:
            return self.myPow(x * x, int(n / 2)) * ([1, x][n % 2])
        else:
            return self.myPow(x * x, int(n / 2)) * ([1, 1/x][n % 2])
```