# Why does this code raise IndexError in certain situation?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

My function is like this:

input:

```
8
```

output:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

So this is to create a list to store input_number binary numbers start from 0.
Here is my code (Correct version):

```
import math

input_num = 8
max_bit = math.ceil(math.log(input_num, 2))

list_Bin = [None] * input_num

for i in range(input_num):
    extra_d = max_bit - len(bin(i)[2:])
    list_Bin[i] = '0'*extra_d + bin(i)[2:]

print(list_Bin)
```

This code works well. But if I change one line of the code:

```
list_Bin = [None] * input_num
```

to

```
list_Bin = [] * input_num
```

It will raise IndexError.

I really want to know why, since I have met this problem many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `[None]` and `[]`. `[None]` is a list with **one** member, which is `None`. But `[]` is an empty list with **zero** member.

When you do `[None] * input_num` you create a new list with `None` members, as many as `input_num` times.

But when you do `[] * input_num`, there is no member to begin with. Thus you still have an empty list which naturally cannot be indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But can I use .append to give the empty list value?

Comment: @MarsLee it is good to see you [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837794/can-someone-explain-this-recursive-for-me). ;) Yes, an empty list is a *list* and thus you may append it with an item, like any other list does

Comment: Definitely! Thank you for helping me yesterday! I totally understood it! Thank you :)

Comment: @MarsLee great. ;) yes, it is as you said, we meet again shortly... have a good day!

Comment: I believe we will meet soon again, since I still have a lot of problems haha. Hope you have a lovely day :)

Answer (score 5):

An empty list is like 0; no matter what you multiply it by, the answer is still an empty list.

```
>>> [] == []*8
True
```

And `[][x]` will raise an `IndexError` for any value `x`.

Comment: Wow! I got it! THis is super clear! So if I want to give the empty list value, the only way is .append? I am really appreciate for your answering ;)

Comment: Yes, an empty list is like any other list; it just doesn't have any values. You can take its length with len (and like any other list, a valid index `i` is `0 <= i < len([]) == 0`-- and there are no integers that are greater than or equal to 0 *and* less than 0), append to it (`l = []; l.append(3); l == [3]`), etc.